# R function to generate predictions from ratings

Tags: performance, r, clustering, data-mining

I am trying to improve the run time of a program I wrote in R. Generally, what I am doing is feeding a function a data frame of values and generating a prediction off of operations on specific columns. The function is a custom function that is being used with `sapply` (code below). What I'm doing is much too large to provide any meaningful example, so instead I will try to describe the inputs to the process. I know this will restrict how helpful answers can be, but I am interested in any ideas for optimizing the time it takes me to compute a prediction. Currently it is taking me about 10 seconds to generate one prediction (running the `sapply` for one line of a dataframe).

```
mean_rating <- function(df){
  user<-df$user
  movie<-df$movie
  u_row<-which(U_lookup == user)[1]
  m_row<-which(M_lookup==movie)[1]

  knn_match<- knn_txt[u_row,1:100]

  knn_match1<-as.numeric(unlist(knn_match))

  dfm_test<- dfm[knn_match1,]

  dfm_mov<- dfm_test[,m_row] # row number from DFM associated with the query_movie
  C<-mean(dfm_mov)

}

test<-sapply(1:nrow(probe_test),function(x) mean_rating(probe_test[x,]))
```

Inputs: dfm is my main data matrix, users in the rows and movies in the columns. Very sparse.

```
> str(dfm)
Formal class 'dgTMatrix' [package "Matrix"] with 6 slots
  ..@ i       : int [1:99072112] 378 1137 1755 1893 2359 3156 3423 4380 5103 6762 ...
  ..@ j       : int [1:99072112] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
  ..@ Dim     : int [1:2] 480189 17770
  ..@ Dimnames:List of 2
  .. ..$ : NULL
  .. ..$ : NULL
  ..@ x       : num [1:99072112] 4 5 4 1 4 5 4 5 3 3 ...
  ..@ factors : list()
```

probe_test is my test set, the set I'm trying to predict for. The actual probe test contains approximately 1.4 million rows but I am trying it on a subset first to optimize the time. It is being fed into my function.

```
> str(probe_test)
'data.frame':   6 obs. of  6 variables:
 $ X          : int  1 2 3 4 5 6
 $ movie      : int  1 1 1 1 1 1
 $ user       : int  1027056 1059319 1149588 1283744 1394012 1406595
 $ Rating     : int  3 3 4 3 5 4
 $ Rating_Date: Factor w/ 1929 levels "2000-01-06","2000-01-08",..: 1901 1847 1911 1312 1917 1803
 $ Indicator  : int  1 1 1 1 1 1
```

U_lookup is the lookup I use to convert between user id and the line of the matrix a user is in since we lose user id's when they are converted to a sparse matrix.

```
> str(U_lookup)
'data.frame':   480189 obs. of  1 variable:
 $ x: int  10 100000 1000004 1000027 1000033 1000035 1000038 1000051 1000053 1000057 ...
```

M_lookup is the lookup I use to convert between movie id and the column of a matrix a movie is in for similar reasons as above.

```
> str(M_lookup)
'data.frame':   17770 obs. of  1 variable:
 $ x: int  1 10 100 1000 10000 10001 10002 10003 10004 10005 ...
```

knn_text contains the 100 nearest neighbors for all the lines of dfm

```
> str(knn_txt)
'data.frame':   480189 obs. of  200 variables:
```

Does anyone have suggestions on how I could improve performance within R? Does anyone have other language suggestions? I am slightly familiar with Python so I've been looking into that one, but if anyone has specific tips on redoing this in Python I would be grateful as I'm very inexperienced with it.

Comment: @user2355903 Can you supply code that generates or simulates your data, so we can run your code? Otherwise it is really hard to help you.

Comment: I made a new question here, if you were interested in looking at it: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/199873/r-function-to-generate-predictions-from-ratings-and-save-results

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Comment: So I should make a new question with example data?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [R Function to Generate Predictions from Ratings and Save Results](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/199873/r-function-to-generate-predictions-from-ratings-and-save-results)

Comment: @AkselA From my understanding, it's more of a follow up question, considering the OP posted the link itself. Maybe I'm wrong though.

Comment: @TopinFrassi: They are essentially the same question. Neither of them are of particularly high quality, but the later one seems to include more useful information.

Comment: @AkselA The code is not the same, it's not a duplicate. Please take a look at [How do we define duplicate questions?](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8/52915) If you stand by the idea it's a duplicate, please [find me in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8595/the-2nd-monitor). I'm not well versed in R, but to an outside the approaches look dissimilar enough to be their own question.

Answer (score 1):

Without exact your data I could think of some improvements.
Trying to avoid redundant operations.

```
# order data.frame by users and movies
probe_test <- probe_test[with(probe_test, order(user, move)), ]
# initialize resulting column
probe_test$res <- rep(as.numeric(NA), nrow(probe_test))

knn_txt_red <- knn_txt[, 1:100] # reduce outside of the loop
for (user in unique(probe_test$user)) { # for each unique user
  u_row <- which(U_lookup == user)[1] # get your id
  knn_match <- knn_txt_red[u_row, ]
  knn_match1 <- as.numeric(unlist(knn_match))
  userI <- probe_test$user == user
  movies <- probe_test$movie[userI] #get all user movies
  m_row <- which(M_lookup %in% movies) # get indexes
  dfm_mov <- dfm[knn_match1, m_row] #select all cols of those movies for user
  x <- colMeans(dfm_mov) # calculate mean for each row
  probe_test[userI, 'res'] <- x # add the results to data.frame
}
```

As I do not have your data, there are probably/maybe some errors in code.

There are probably better ways to do this, but as I mentioned, it is hard to think of any without any example data.

Comment: Thank you for the tip. I can see what you're saying here, if we can avoid re subsetting the sparse matrix multiple times that could be very helpful. I will try to post some example data later today and see if that is helpful to people.